# Vuejs with laravel displaying error is not working

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.8

Trying to display validation error in browser using vuejs and laravel.
Here is my js and blade file code:

```
class Errors {
    //need to store the error 
    constructor() {
        this.errors = {};
    }
    // will get and return the error here
    get(field) {

        if (this.errors[field]) {

            return this.errors[field][0];
        }
    }

    record(errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }
}

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    
    data: {
        name: '',
        description: '',
        errors: new Errors()

    },

    methods: {
        onSubmit() {
            axios.post('/projects',this.$data)
                .then(response => alert('Success'))
                .catch(error => this.errors.record(error.response.data));

        }
    }
});
```

And in blade file i am using like:

```
<span class="help is-danger" v-text="errors.get('description')"></span>
```

And i am getting this error while running the file in browser:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: errors.get is not a function"
```

Need help to solve this.

Comment: you forgot to use Errors class. in `data` it should be: `errors: new Errors()`

Comment: yes I forgot to write here but i have used that.  Thank you by the way for mention this.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out by adding my line like

```
.catch(error => this.errors.record(error.response.data.errors));
```

[image]